# Can't update Wordpress 4.0

Tags: updates

I'm trying to update wordpress but when I click update, it give me the error msg "Apologies, but we were unable to find what you were looking for. Perhaps searching will help."

Can anyone advise?

Thank you

Comment: Sometimes this error appears when permalinks are an issue. Save the default and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Execute your update during a low activity time just in case something goes wrong.

Follow [this link](http://websynthesis.com/updating-wordpress/)

Comment: If that doesn't work you can always (after making a complete file and database backup, storing both locally on your computer) download the desired version of WordPress, extract it and then FTP them over the top.